# JavaScript to trim after n characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, trim

I have a HTML page which shows a Name dynamically. Now this name (FN LN) can be upto 240 charcaters. But at the UI side, I want to trim the FN/LN after about 50 characters and replace with ...

How can I do this using Javascript/jQuery

Comment: FN.substring(0, 50); will this help you...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$("#FN, #LN").each (function () {
  if ($(this).text().length > 50)
    $(this).text($(this).text().substring(0,50) + '...');
});
```

This should work.

Answer (score 10):

Something as simple as:

```
if (name.length > 50) {
    name = name.substr(0,50)+'...';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ($('#name').text().length > 50)
{
    $('#name').text( $('#name').text().substring(0,50)+"..." );
}
```

But you can also use CSS for this: http://mattsnider.com/css/css-string-truncation-with-ellipsis/

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that myself a minute ago. Thats why I love stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 3):

here's a regex way to do that :

```
text.replace(/(^.{50}).*$/,'$1...');
```

Since you've asked, if you want to jqueryfy this functionality, you can make a plugin out of it :

```
$.fn.trimAfter(n,replacement){
    replacement = replacement || "...";
    return this.each(function(i,el){
        $(el).text($(el).text().substring(n) + replacement);
    });
}
```

And use it like this :

```
$("#FN, #LN").trimAfter(50,'...');
```